# Помогите пофиксить код

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код получает на вход массив и должна реализовывать 2 функции по нахождению:

1. Суммы положительных элементов стоящих на чётных местах
2. Произведение отрицательных элементов стоящих на нечётных местах

```
vvod=int(input('размер массива '))
for i in range(0,vvod):
 vvod=int(input('индекс '+str(i)+' число: '))
 array.append(vvod)
 print('получившийся массив:' + str(array))
 n=1
 sume=0
 proiz=1
 log=False
for i in array:
  if n%2==0 and i>0: 
    sume+=i
    n+=1
    n=1
    for i in array:
      if n%2!=0:
        if i<0:
          proiz=proiz*i
          log=True
          n+=1
          if log==False:
            proiz=0
            print('Суммы положительных элементов стоящих на чётных местах '+str(sume))
            print('Произведение отрицательных элементов стоящих на нечётных местах '+str(proiz))
```

Comment: А где вопрос? Описание проблемы? Вы описали то, что хотите сделать, но ни слова не сказали о том, что у Вас не получается.

Comment: Верно. Почему-то не выполняются операторы FOR, код заканчивает свою работу после получения 10 индексов/значений на вход и просто выводит весь массив.

Comment: Вполне возможно, что они у Вас выполняются, только Вы этого не видите, так как не выполняется вывод. У Вас странная переменная log. При наличии в массиве на нечетной позиции хоть одного отрицательного числа  она примет значение True, и, тем самым, заблокирует вывод результатов. Проверьте, нужна ли она Вам, и делает ли она именно то, что Вы хотели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Намудрили с алгоритмом подсчета, можно намного проще сделать. Пример:

```
array = [4, 2, 2, -3, -2, 0, 6, 5, 6, -1, 6, 2, 6, -3, -3, -2, 0, 3, 5, 5]

total_sum = 0
total_prod = 1

for i, x in enumerate(array):
    # Четный индекс, положительное число
    if i % 2 == 0 and x > 0:
        total_sum += x

    # Нечетный индекс, отрицательное число
    if i % 2 == 1 and x < 0:
        total_prod *= x

print(total_sum)   # 35
print(total_prod)  # 18
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

[Питон 3.8+](https://tio.run/##TYzNCoMwEITveYo5RmjE39ZK2xcpPQSqGNBkSSLYp0@3iFD2MMPMfEufODlbd@RTMgs5H7HoOAmhccdsQpSLJmlsPMFYWqPM8kCzYc0yIchzI8O6yA1mxIYHCgxzGFhG5zkwFvpZ9n314v0@//3Pybv3Ad0OqPyHih1KqUSFGg1anKEaqBaKzQWqg7oyyvcF):

```
import math

a = list(map(int, input().split()))

print(sum(x if x > 0 else 0 for x in a[1::2]))
print(math.prod(x if x < 0 else 1 for x in a[0::2]))
```